# Nesting inner array as value in pre-existing multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array called:

```
$fragment = array($fragment);
```

Which has the following three values:

1. `["<div class=\"alert alert_error mt20\"><a class=\"js-alert-close close\"><\/a>Please enter a  title <\/div>"]`
2. `["<div class=\"alert alert_error mt20\"><a class=\"js-alert-close close\"><\/a>Enter a valid source URL (e.g. http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Penguins) <\/div>"]`
3. `["<div class=\"alert alert_error mt20\"><a class=\"js-alert-close close\"><\/a>Please choose a category <\/div>"]`

I want to merge that array into another array (into the `'fragment'` key) which looks like:

```
$toReturn = array(
    'status' => $status,
    'formData' => $formData,
    'inputs' => $inputs,
    'fragment' => $fragment
);
```

But every time I do so, it just adds the first value of `$fragment` which is:

1. `"<div class=\"alert alert_error mt20\"><a class=\"js-alert-close close\"><\/a>Please enter a title <\/div>"`

How can I add all three values from `$fragment` into my `$toReturn` array instead?

Comment: What has this to do with Json?

Comment: @hakre because I'm using json_encode within my View in CakePHP which is what the array is structured for. Guess I should have been more verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one long string with the three array entries by concatenating them, e.g. with the popular [`implode`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/implode) function:

```
$fragment = implode("", $fragment);
```

Comment: Actually ended going with array_unshift which is what I needed but thanks this gave me the idea to use that.